# Correct way to reset the data of a modal window to default if the modal is closed using Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a property called `addServerWindow` which is set to false by default. If `addServerWindow` is false, a `div` is rendered which sets `addServerWindow` to true when clicked. Once `addServerWindow` is true, a `div` which contains a `form` is rendered that has some 2 way data binded inputs. Finally, there's a absolutely positioned black screen `div` which sets `addServerWindow` to false when clicked.

Now I am curious, what is the best way to reset the data of the modal window when it is closed through a click to the black screen. Right now, if a user opens the modal window, types something in the input, closes the modal and then opens the modal again, the modal remembers what the user had typed earlier. I would like for the modal data to reset if the user clicks the black screen.

I could create a function in which I could hardcode all properties and set them to their defaults but I'm not quite sure if this is the correct way

Part of my template:

```
<div class='add-server' @click='addServerWindow = true'></div>

<div class="create-server-form-container" v-if='addServerWindow'>
    <form class="create-server-form" @submit='createServer($event)'>
        <div class="inputs-container">
            <div class="input-container">
                <label class='text-input-label' :for="serverName">server name</label>
                <input type="text" v-model="serverName" placeholder="Enter a server name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="button-container">
            <button type="submit" name="button">Create</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="black-screen" @click='addServerWindow = false'></div>
</div>
```

The data of the script:

```
    data(){
    return {
        addServerWindow: false,
        serverName: ''
    }
},
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with you creating a function and setting the values to their default when the modal is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bobimaru.
I would prefer to do a function which toggles the addServerWindow and clears the serverName at the same time.

```
methods:{
    toggleServerForm(){
       this.addServerWindow = !this.addServerWindow
       this.serverName = ''
    }
}
```